# hierarchical clustering on correlations in Python scipy/numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, machine-learning, scipy

How can I run hierarchical clustering on a correlation matrix in `scipy`/`numpy`?  I have a matrix of 100 rows by 9 columns, and I'd like to hierarchically cluster by correlations of each entry across the 9 conditions.  I'd like to use 1-pearson correlation as the distances for clustering.  Assuming I have a `numpy` array `X` that contains the 100 x 9 matrix, how can I do this?

I tried using hcluster, based on this example:

```
Y=pdist(X, 'seuclidean')
Z=linkage(Y, 'single')
dendrogram(Z, color_threshold=0)
```

However, `pdist` is not what I want, since that's a euclidean distance.  Any ideas?

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just change the metric to `correlation` so that the first line becomes:

```
Y=pdist(X, 'correlation')
```

However, I believe that the code can be simplified to just:

```
Z=linkage(X, 'single', 'correlation')
dendrogram(Z, color_threshold=0)
```

because linkage will take care of the pdist for you.

Comment: Does 'correlation' here mean Pearson or Spearman?  Also, shouldn't it be 1 - pearson in order to be a valid distance metric that can be used for pdist?  Does pdist do that automatically?  thanks.

Comment: It looks like it is 1 - pearson to me. You can look at it yourself in site-packages/scipy/spatial/distance.py

Comment: It's fairly rare for "correlation" mentioned alone to mean Spearman correlation. Usually if it's Spearman people will say so, otherwise assume Pearson.

Comment: I you want the correlations between the columns, you need to pass the transpose of X:

Z=linkage(X.T, 'single', 'correlation')

Answer (score 0):

I find it helpful to perform and visualize the hierarchical clustering using the seaborn clustermap (which uses underneath scipy for the clustering), after having used 'correlation' as a metric for pdist:

```
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

D = squareform(pdist(X.T, 'correlation'))
h = sns.clustermap(D, cmap='Reds')
```

You can also recover the corresponding linkage matrix and plot the dendrogram

```
Z = h.dendrogram_col.linkage    
dendrogram(Z, color_threshold=0)
```